# why a command in makefile is always executed even of all Prerequisites is nothing change?

Tags: c, makefile

I have a C project ,  the struct is as the last part of this questions,
there is a main makefile in root and 3 makefile in  AppCode\Comp2 AppCode\Comp3 AppCode\headlamp

I want to :

1. compile all c file in  AppCode\Comp2  to object files , then archinve these object file  to a library file (a file)
2. do the same step as 1 for every subdirectory in AppCode ,in this case are AppCode\Comp3 AppCode\headlamp
3. search all object files (*.o) in all directories expect AppCode in $(OBJ_FILES)
4. link all a files in AppCode $(ALL_a_in_AppCode) and o files $(OBJ_FILES) to a elf file
5. create hex file based on elf file

the main makefile will  call the sub-dir's makefile ,

there is my main makefile in root :

```
include rules.mk

rwildcard=$(wildcard $1$2)$(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2))
ALL_C_in_AppCode := $(call rwildcard,./AppCode,*.c)
ALL_O_in_AppCode := $(call rwildcard,./AppCode,*.o)
ALL_a_in_AppCode := $(call rwildcard,./AppCode,*.a)

AppCodeSubDirs := $(wildcard AppCode/**)
OBJPATH_IN_AppCode :=$(addsuffix /obj,$(AppCodeSubDirs))
APATH_IN_AppCode :=$(addsuffix /lib,$(AppCodeSubDirs))

APPCode_DIR = .\APPCode
CDD_dir =.\CDD
DemoAppCode_dir = .\DemoAppCode
Intergration_dir =.\Intergration
MCAL_dir=.\MCAL

VOS_BSW_dir=.\VOS\BSW
VOS_BSW_Config_dir=.\VOS\BSW_config
VOS_erika_dir=.\VOS\erika
VOS_LIB_dir=.\VOS\Lib



OBJ_FILES = $(wildcard $(CDD_dir)/*.o)
OBJ_FILES += $(wildcard $(DemoAppCode_dir)/*.o)
OBJ_FILES += $(wildcard $(Intergration_dir)/*.o)
OBJ_FILES += $(wildcard $(MCAL_dir)/*.o)
OBJ_FILES += $(wildcard $(VOS_BSW_dir)/*.o)
OBJ_FILES += $(wildcard $(VOS_BSW_Config_dir)/*.o)
OBJ_FILES += $(wildcard $(VOS_erika_dir)/*.o)
OBJ_FILES += $(wildcard $(VOS_LIB_dir)/*.o) 


LDFLAGS = -mtc162 -T 

all:erika3app.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) --set-start 0x0000 -R .ram -R .sbRam -R .sb_fix_ram -I elf32-tricore -O ihex erika3app.elf erika3app.hex

erika3app.elf:$(OBJ_FILES)  AppCodeLib
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) .\Intergration\out\ee_tc_gcc_flash.ld -nostartfiles -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=erika3app.map   -L . -L .\Intergration\out\ -L .\Intergration\erika\mk   $(OBJ_FILES) -o "erika3app.elf" -L .\Intergration\erika\lib -Wl,--start-group  -lee -Wl,--end-group

AppCodeLib: $(AppCodeSubDirs)

$(AppCodeSubDirs):
    make -C $@


clean:
    -rm -rf $(OBJPATH_IN_AppCode)   $(APATH_IN_AppCode) erika3app.hex erika3app.elf erika3app.map


print-%: ; @echo $* = $($*) 

.PHONY:$(AppCodeSubDirs)
```

if i execute make , it seems that  the command for erika3app.elf and all is always executed ,
as follow (i omit some meamless o files):
anyone can tell me why these two commands are always execute and how to fix it ?
Thanks!

```
PS D:\TEST\project> .\build.bat
make -C AppCode/headlamp
make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/TEST/project/AppCode/headlamp'
C:\VOS_tools_repo\hightec_ifx\v4.9.2.0\bin\tricore-ar.exe csr  lib/libheadlamp.a   obj/app1.o obj/app21.o obj/app2.o
make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/TEST/project/AppCode/headlamp'
make -C AppCode/Comp3
make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/TEST/project/AppCode/Comp3'
C:\VOS_tools_repo\hightec_ifx\v4.9.2.0\bin\tricore-ar.exe csr  lib/libComp3.a   obj/33.o
make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/TEST/project/AppCode/Comp3'
make -C AppCode/Comp2
make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/TEST/project/AppCode/Comp2'
C:\VOS_tools_repo\hightec_ifx\v4.9.2.0\bin\tricore-ar.exe csr  lib/libComp2.a   obj/22.o
make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/TEST/project/AppCode/Comp2'
C:\VOS_tools_repo\hightec_ifx\v4.9.2.0\bin\tricore-gcc.exe -mtc162 -T  .\Intergration\out\ee_tc_gcc_flash.ld -nostartfiles -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=erika3app.map   -L . -L .\Intergration\out\ -L .\Intergration\erika\mk    .\DemoAppCode/Rte_Chas_SA_FDD_IBCInfo.c.o .\VOS\Lib/qn_strcpy.c.o  -o "erika3app.elf" -L .\Intergration\erika\lib -Wl,--start-group  -lee -Wl,--end-group
C:\VOS_tools_repo\hightec_ifx\v4.9.2.0\bin\tricore-objcopy.exe --set-start 0x0000 -R .ram -R .sbRam -R .sb_fix_ram -I elf32-tricore -O ihex erika3app.elf erika3app.hex
PS D:\TEST\project>
PS D:\TEST\project>
PS D:\TEST\project>
PS D:\TEST\project> .\build.bat
make -C AppCode/headlamp
make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/TEST/project/AppCode/headlamp'
C:\VOS_tools_repo\hightec_ifx\v4.9.2.0\bin\tricore-ar.exe csr  lib/libheadlamp.a   obj/app1.o obj/app21.o obj/app2.o
make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/TEST/project/AppCode/headlamp'
make -C AppCode/Comp3
make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/TEST/project/AppCode/Comp3'
C:\VOS_tools_repo\hightec_ifx\v4.9.2.0\bin\tricore-ar.exe csr  lib/libComp3.a   obj/33.o
make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/TEST/project/AppCode/Comp3'
make -C AppCode/Comp2
make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/TEST/project/AppCode/Comp2'
C:\VOS_tools_repo\hightec_ifx\v4.9.2.0\bin\tricore-ar.exe csr  lib/libComp2.a   obj/22.o
make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/TEST/project/AppCode/Comp2'
C:\VOS_tools_repo\hightec_ifx\v4.9.2.0\bin\tricore-gcc.exe -mtc162 -T  .\Intergration\out\ee_tc_gcc_flash.ld -nostartfiles -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=erika3app.map   -L . -L .\Intergration\out\ -L .\Intergration\erika\mk    .\DemoAppCode/Rte_Chas_SA_FDD_IBCInfo.c.o .\DemoAppCode/Rte_EN_SA_FDD_WaterTemp1Info.c.o ..\VOS\Lib/qn_strnlen.c.o .\VOS\Lib/qn_memset.c.o .\VOS\Lib/qn_strncpy.c.o .\VOS\Lib/qn_strlen.c.o .\VOS\Lib/qn_strcpy.c.o  -o "erika3app.elf" -L .\Intergration\erika\lib -Wl,--start-group  -lee -Wl,--end-group
C:\VOS_tools_repo\hightec_ifx\v4.9.2.0\bin\tricore-objcopy.exe --set-start 0x0000 -R .ram -R .sbRam -R .sb_fix_ram -I elf32-tricore -O ihex erika3app.elf erika3app.hex
PS D:\TEST\project>
```

here is my  project struct:

```
D:.
|   build.bat
|   clean.bat
|   makefile
|   rules.mk
|
+---AppCode
|   +---Comp2
|   |   |   22.c
|   |   |   makefile
|   |   |
|   |
|   +---Comp3
|   |   |   33.c
|   |   |   makefile
|   |   |
|   |
|   \---headlamp
|       |   makefile
|       |
|       +---left
|       |       app1.c
|       |       app1.h
|       |
|       \---right
|           |   app2.c
|           |   app2.h
|           |
|           \---rightright
|                   app21.c
|
+---CDD
|   \---include
+---DemoAppCode
|       Rte_Chas_SA_FDD_IBCInfo.c.o
|
+---Intergration
|   |   applSignature.oil
|   |   Dcm_CallOut.c.o
|   |
|   +---erika
|   |   +---lib
|   |   |       libee.a
|   |   |
|   |   \---mk
|   |           ee.mk
|   |           ee_arch_cfg.mk
|   |
|   \---out
|           ee_applcfg.h
|
+---MCAL
|       Can_17_McmCan.c.o
|       Wdg_17_Scu_PBcfg.c.o
|
+---other
\---VOS
    +---BSW
    |       api_standalone.c.o
    |
    +---BSW_Config
    |       BswMBswMConfig_0_CommonPBcfg.c.o
    |       WdgM_PBcfg.c.o
    |
    +---erika
    |       ee_bss_data_init.c.o
    |       ee_oscfg.c.o
    |       osSignature.oil
    |
    \---LIB
            libee.a
            qn_memcpy.c.o
```

Comment: Try `.PHONY: $(AppCodeSubDirs) all AppCodeLib clean`.

Comment: If I understand your Makefile correct, then the only library that gets linked to the program is `-lee`, not any of the libraries in `AppCode/*`. Instead of trying to find the files to be compiled/linked by a wildcard search I recommend to explicitly list the files you want to use in all your Makefiles. It is convenient to have a Makefile that finds everything automatically, but it might be more difficult to find errors if something goes wrong or if there are missing or additional files.

Comment: @ABacker  .PHONY: $(AppCodeSubDirs) all AppCodeLib clean 
this is also execute the  $(LD) and $(OBJCOPY) even nothing is changed

Answer (score 0):

The command for `all` is executed because it does not create a file named `all`. That's why it will always be executed.

To prevent this you should not use any command for the `all` target but only for targets that correspond to a file of the same name.

The problem with `erika3app.elf` is probably related to `AppCodeLib` which also seems to be a phony target. `make` does not know what files might get updated by the rules to build `AppCodeLib`. You should use this as a dependency for the files that will actually be created/updated by this target. Or maybe `AppCodeLib` updates any of the object files?

The example below assumes that the rules for `AppCodeLib` will create/update the object files in `$(OBJ_FILES)`.

**Example:**

```
# ...

.PHONY: all AppCodeLib

all: erika3app.hex

erika3app.hex: erika3app.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) --set-start 0x0000 -R .ram -R .sbRam -R .sb_fix_ram -I elf32-tricore -O ihex erika3app.elf 

erika3app.elf: $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) .\Intergration\out\ee_tc_gcc_flash.ld -nostartfiles -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=erika3app.map   -L . -L .\Intergration\out\ -L .\Intergration\erika\mk   $(OBJ_FILES) -o "erika3app.elf" -L .\Intergration\erika\lib -Wl,--start-group  -lee -Wl,--end-group

$(OBJ_FILES): AppCodeLib

AppCodeLib: $(AppCodeSubDirs)

# ...
```

If you create libraries for code in the subdirectories and link these libraries to your application you might need dependencies for the libraies as well.

You might consider using CMake for such a complex project.

Comment: hello @Bodo ,thanks for your answer.   the requirement is : create libs for every subdirectory in AppCode. $(OBJ_FILES) is all  o files in other folder.  so the libs is no releation with $(OBJ_FILES).  i wish  all  in one makefile. but it hard to me. so i write every sub makefile which used to generate every lib in AppCode.

Comment: @chenx319 Please add all requirements to the question. You can edit it by clicking on the gray word `Edit` below the question. It is unclear what libs are created by `AppCodeLib` and how thex are linked to your application. Getting the dependencies right is not easy. Without more details it is difficult to propose a solution. This really looks like a project that could take advantage of using CMake instead of hand-written Makefiles.

Comment: oh ,sorry , I updated my question. and I change "all:erika3app.elf" to "erika3app.hex:erika3app.elf", then i make twice  ,  the command  $(LD) and $(OBJCOPY) still run even nothing changed. maybe the cause is in ".PHONY:$(AppCodeSubDirs)",  but if i remove the ".PHONY:$(AppCodeSubDirs)', all makefile in AppCode is not called ,  currently I think learn CMake may take longtime ,I still  try find a solution use makefile, Thanks!

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you changed and what happens now. Please edit your question and **add** the modified Makefile(s) and the output of the second `make` command.

Answer (score 0):

Your targets `all/AppCodeLib/$(AppCodeSubDirs)` are phony targets, which means they are not files on disk, so their rules will be executed every time you make, so as targets depend on them. For example, your `$(OBJCOPY)` command will not generate a file named "`all`", and your `erika3app.elf` depends on `AppCodeLib` which is not a file so nowhere to know it is "ready" or not.

```
all:erika3app.elf
    $(OBJCOPY) --set-start 0x0000 -R .ram -R .sbRam -R .sb_fix_ram -I elf32-tricore -O ihex erika3app.elf erika3app.hex

erika3app.elf:$(OBJ_FILES)  AppCodeLib
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) .\Intergration\out\ee_tc_gcc_flash.ld -nostartfiles -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=erika3app.map   -L . -L .\Intergration\out\ -L .\Intergration\erika\mk   $(OBJ_FILES) -o "erika3app.elf" -L .\Intergration\erika\lib -Wl,--start-group  -lee -Wl,--end-group

AppCodeLib: $(AppCodeSubDirs)

$(AppCodeSubDirs):
    make -C $@
```

To fix this, you need to put your commands under non-phony targets, for example, if your `$(OBJCOPY)` command generates a file named "ihex" (I'm not sure about this), you could:

```
all: erika3app.elf ihex

ihex:
    $(OBJCOPY) --set-start 0x0000 -R .ram -R .sbRam -R .sb_fix_ram -I elf32-tricore -O ihex erika3app.elf erika3app.hex
```

And make `AppCodeLib` depends on actual files, for example

```
AppCodeLib: AppCode\Comp2\22.a AppCode\Comp3\33.a ...

AppCode\Comp2\22.a:
    make -C AppCode\Comp2

AppCode\Comp3\33.a:
    make -C AppCode\Comp3

# Use `%` to make a pattern
```

The main point is that you need to depend on actual files.

---

EDIT:

A simple example:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -W -Wall -g
LFLAGS = -lm

all: AppCodeLib main.x

AppCodeSubDirs = AppCode/Comp2 AppCode/Comp3
Libs = AppCode/Comp2/22.o AppCode/Comp3/33.o # tested with .o, make it .a

main.x: main_c.c $(Libs) # depends on real files
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LFLAGS)

AppCodeLib: $(AppCodeSubDirs)

$(AppCodeSubDirs):
    make -C $@

.PHONY: all AppCodeLib $(AppCodeSubDirs)
```

Comment: @ABachker ,  thanks for you answer! can you kindly show me how to write a pattern for every a file (eg:22.a) using "%", and how to add prerequisites  for 22.a in a easy way . as  I write it as you example ,  if I change 22.c  , the  "make -C AppCode\Comp2" is not executed, and 22.a is not updated